# Which material has the highest diamagnetism?

Tags: magnetic-fields, material-science

I know that graphite and bismuth have the strongest diamagnetism, but between the two, which one is stronger?

Comment: I deleted a comment that looked like an answer to the question. Please keep in mind that comments are meant for requesting clarifications and suggesting improvements, not for answering.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of insufficient research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some might not consider this diamagnetic, but superconductors are the most resistant to magnetic fields. By the Messiner effect, they expel all magnetic fields except for a thin layer at the edge. A superconductor is ~2500 times more diamagnetic than pyrolytic carbon, one of the most diamagnetic compounds. Superconductors normally require really low temperatures to form, so aren't that practical for most use cases

Answering the question, Bismuth is ~10 times more diamagnetic than graphite. Graphite would have $1.6 \cdot 10^{-5}$ times less magnetic field within it than vacuum, while for Bismuth it's $1.7 \cdot 10^{-4}$.

Comment: @SebastianRiese the units are not arbitrary, diamagnetic strength tells you the ratio between the applied field and the resulting induced diamagnetic field. A strength of 1 (like the case of superconductors), means the field has an equal and opposite induced diamagnetic field cancelling it out.

Comment: @user157879 They are no more, my comment referenced an earlier version (where the values multiplied by $10^5$ where stated without explanation).